# node.js actions on google save conversation data

Tags: javascript, node.js, salesforce, actions-on-google

I have an issue where I can return data from an AXIOS request but I cannot save that data to the conversation user storage (conv.user.storage.caseNumber) using Actions on Google Node.js library. I've tried many different approaches but none are working. I can save data from the intent fine (ex. conv.user.storage.subject and conv.user.storage.description). I've verified via console.log() that the data (i.e. caseNumber) is being returned properly in the response. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
  // Index
    const SalesForceProxy = require('./classes/SalesForceProxy');
    let proxy = new SalesForceProxy();
    app.intent('getDescription - yes - CreateConfirmation', proxy.createCase);

    // Proxy.js

    module.exports = function () {

    this.createCase = function (conv) {

    return new Promise(function( resolve, reject) {
     axios.post('https://mysite.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',querystring.stringify(params)).then(function(response){

                    var caseData =  {
                        "account" : conv.user.storage.accountId,
                        "recordType" : conv.user.storage.recordTypeId,
                        "priority" : conv.user.storage.priority,
                        "subject" : conv.user.storage.subject,
                        "description" : conv.user.storage.description
                    };

                    axios.post('https://mysite.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/voicetocase/create',caseData,
                    {
                        headers:  
                        {
                            'Authorization': "Bearer " + response.data.access_token,
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }      
                    }
                    )
                    .then(function(response){
                       conv.user.storage.caseNumber = response.data.caseNumber;
                    }.bind({conv: conv}))
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                    resolve()

            }.bind({conv: conv})).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                reject(err);
            }); 

         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're resolving the promise too soon, before you get to set the user storage, which is a second promise.

```
axiom.post(...)
  .then() {
      conv.user.storage.X = "";
      resolve();
  }
```

This should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working. I'm new to promises and Actions on Google.